# How to use SQL with Agens Graph in AGCloud's AGViewer if possible

Tags: apache-age, agens-graph

I'm trying to use the SQL syntax in Agens Graph but I don't know to use it.

I tried the following query

> SELECT * FROM MATCH result = ()-[]->() RETURN result;

Or

SELECT * FROM GRAPH MATCH result = ()-[]->() RETURN result;

but both gives me the following error

> Syntax error at or near "MATCH"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to use SQL to wrap Cypher queries in AGViewer, instead just enter Cypher queries directly, for example:

```
SELECT * FROM cypher('graph_name', $$ MATCH result = ()-[]->() RETURN result $$) as (result agtype);
```

Can be simplified into the following in AGViewer:

```
MATCH result = ()-[]->() RETURN result;
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `SELECT * FROM` to run it. You only have to use the cypher to run the queries.

There is an example that you can use:

`MATCH (n1)-[r]->(n2) RETURN n1, r, n2;`

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `SELECT * FROM` and just use Cypher language.

Comment: could you provide me an example of that

Comment: Yes of course. ```MATCH result = ()-[]->() RETURN result;``` would be for example the first command

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT * FROM MATCH result = ()-[]->() RETURN result;`

This seems incorrect. Select all from match? Usually after the `FROM` clause we enter the database name in SQL or the table name e.t.c.

Try dropping the `SELECT` clause and just use Cypher language.

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT *` clause should be avoided when using SQL syntax in Agens Graph.
`Cypher` queries in Agens Graph be used, which is the query language specifically used for graph databases.

Here is how the query will look like:

```
MATCH result = ()-[]->()
RETURN result;
```